# About matrix diagonalization in C from the characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, diagonalization

Ok the excercise is:

You have one characteristic polynomial, it's:

$\lambda^4 + \lambda^2$

Find two matrixes with this polynomial, one of them diagolalizable in C and the other one not.

so the first thing i have done is to find a matrix wich had this polynomial. I have found.

\begin{pmatrix}
 0&0  &-1 &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &0 \\ 
 1&0  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}

For ($A-\lambda I)=0$ we have:

\begin{pmatrix}
 -\lambda &0  &-1 &0 \\ 
 0&-\lambda  &0  &0 \\ 
 1&0  &-\lambda  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &-\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}

wich if im not wrong gives us the $p(A)$=$\lambda^4 + \lambda^2$.

This matrix, again if im not wrong, is diagonalizable in C. Now if i need to find another one not diagonalizable i need to build another matrix from scratches or, as i suspect, there is a simple method to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that we're talking about matrices with real entries.

The easiest way to approach this problem is to build examples using either Jordan normal form or the [real Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices).  Another approach is to build block diagonal matrices where each block is a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

That's the general method, let's look at your approach.  It turns out that your example is essentially the same as 
$$
\pmatrix{0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}
$$
which is the "real Jordan form" associated with the diagonalizable matrix here.  To get this from your answer, I switch the roles of the $2$nd and $3$rd rows/columns.

One answer to the non-diagonalizable matrix with this characteristic polynomial is
$$
\pmatrix{0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&\color{red}1\\0&0&0&0}
$$
again, this is an example of a "real Jordan form".  We could have also used the companion matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&-1\\
0&0&1&0}
$$

Comment: Hum, seems intresting and powerful! Thanks. Well i need to study Jordan forms and companion matrixes from 0. It doesnt look so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The first observation to make is that your polynomial factors as $X^4+X^2=X^2(X^2+1)$ and that the factors $X^2$ and $X^2+1$ are relatively prime. By the kernel decomposition theorem, for any linear operator with this characteristic polynomial, the space decomposes as a direct sum of stable subspaces for which the characteristic polynomials of the restrictions of the operators are $X^2$ respectively $X^2+1$. You can therefore assume without loss of generality that the matrix is block-diagonal with $2\times2$ diagonal blocks with those characteristic polynomials. The factor $X^2+1$ further factors over $\Bbb C$ as $(X-\mathbf i)(X+\mathbf i)$, which are distinct monic factors of degree$~1$, so that $2\times2$ will be diagonalisable over $\Bbb C$ with eigenvalues $\mathbf i,-\mathbf i$ in all cases; en example with rational entries is the companion matrix $(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix})$ of the polynomial $X^2+1$. On the other hand $X^2$ has a repeated factor, so that part may or may not be diagonalisable; it is diagonalisable only if it is zero, and non diagonalisable if it is any other nilpotent matrix, like $(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{smallmatrix})$ (which happens to be the companion matrix of the polynomial $X^2$).